# JNI ERROR(app bug) : local reference table overflow

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I write my code as

```
jclass clazz = env -> FindClass("java/lang/System");
    jclass globalClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(clazz));
    jmethodID methodId = env -> GetStaticMethodID(globalClass, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring j_file = env -> NewStringUTF(filename.c_str());
    env -> CallStaticVoidMethod(globalClass, methodId, j_file);
    if(env -> ExceptionCheck())
    {
        env -> ExceptionDescribe();
        env -> ExceptionClear();
        LOG_E("Load library error!");
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_E("load library success");
    }
    env -> ReleaseStringUTFChars(j_file, filename.c_str());
    env -> DeleteGlobalRef(clazz);
```

when run it, it's error as

```
A/art(4412): 
art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:113] JNI ERROR (app bug): 
local reference table overflow (max=512)` `A/art(4412): 
art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:113] local reference table dump: 
Last 10 entries (of 512):
```

I don't know why, can you help me?

Comment: Release everything. You're not releasing `j_file.`

Comment: yes , it should be realease everything like `env -> ReleaseStringUTFChars(j_file, filename.c_str());
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(j_file);
    env -> DeleteGlobalRef(j_clazz);
    env -> DeleteLocalRef(clazz);`,but it's also have problem

Comment: According to ART, you have more than 512 local references created by your C++ code during one JNI call. But it doesn't seem to come from your snippet. Do you have anything else running ? Also, please post the end of your debug log, with the "Last 10 entries".

Comment: No, it's just a demo in jni to call java method as `System.load(path)`,

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseStringUTFChars()` doesn't release `j_file`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations).

You need to call `DeleteLocalRef(j_env, j_file)`.

Answer (score -1):

In jni,i rewrite the method of System.nativeLoad,when i call System.load,the System.load call nativeLoad,so...